# Why does using std::ifstream under normal circumstances give me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Sorry if anything I ask is obvious or stupid, I'm about 2 weeks into learning C++.

**EDIT**: I found the problem, it's that in the output from the file, all spaces are changed to a different character. Could someone close this question?

I've been trying to write a program that collects data about hypothetical employees. Recently, I have tried to let it read from a file - however, every time I run the code below (running `fix();`) I get a segmentation fault. Using the breakpoints, I narrowed it down to `std::ifstream file(filename)`. I have tested it and tested it, and have figured out that the `filename` variable is not the issue - it still throws a fault even if I use a string literal. Other things I've found:

-Separating the `std::ifstream file(filename)` and placing it into another file where it cannot reference any of this file's variables works fine.

-The segmentation fault does **NOT** occur when I enter the name of a file that **DOES NOT** exist - instead, it gets to breakpoint 0 (like it should), prints `Error in opening file.` (like it should), and returns false (like it should).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? This has been bothering me for days.

(Also, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with G++ 4.8 - launch flag -std=c++1y)

**EDIT** Ok, this is getting extremely weird. The first thing I did was debug my program using `std::cout`s every other line. This pinpointed the problem to `std::ifstream`. However, under @M.M and @hyde 's reccomendation, I ran my program through the Code::Blocks debugger. It told me that the segmentation fault occurred at `emp->firstName = lineList[2]`. So I commented out that line - but the debugger still says that line is the problem! It's saying that the problem is a ***COMMENTED OUT LINE***! I'm more confused than ever.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "baselibrary.h"
struct Employee
{
    int16_t id; // Employee ID
    std::string lastName; // Employee's last name
    std::string firstName; // Employee's first name
    char middleInitial; // Employee's middle initial
    int16_t age;
    bool gender; // false is male, true is female
    float salary;
    int16_t experience; // # of years working at company
    int16_t department; // Department from Departments::
};
std::vector<Employee> employeeArrayN;
int empNumN{1};
//... tons of snipped out code ...//
bool loadFromDatabaseFileN(){
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Please enter filename to load (with extension): ";
    std::getline(std::cin, filename);
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::cout << "Breakpoint 0!";
    if (!file){
        std::cout << "Error in opening file. ";
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "Breakpoint 1!";
    while (file) // ifstream returns 0 when reaching EOF - 0 is boolean false
    {
        // it's probably OK to ignore the code under here, but you never know...
        std::string lineInput;
        std::cout << "Breakpoint 2!";
        Employee *emp = new Employee;
        std::cout << "Breakpoint 3!";
        ++empNumN;
        std::cout << "Breakpoint 4!";
        std::getline(file, lineInput);
        std::vector<std::string> lineList = splitString(lineInput, ' ');
        int16_t tempId;
        std::cout << "Breakpoint 5!";
        std::stringstream(lineList[0]) >> tempId;
        emp->id = tempId;
        emp->lastName = lineList[1];
        emp->firstName = lineList[2];
        char tempMInit;
        std::stringstream(lineList[3]) >> tempMInit;
        emp->middleInitial = tempMInit;
        int16_t tempAge;
        std::stringstream(lineList[4]) >> tempAge;
        emp->age = tempAge;
        bool tempGend;
        std::stringstream(lineList[5]) >> tempGend;
        emp->gender =  tempGend;
        float tempSalary;
        std::stringstream(lineList[6]) >> tempSalary;
        emp->salary = tempSalary;
        int16_t tempExperience;
        std::stringstream(lineList[7]) >> tempExperience;
        emp->experience = tempExperience;
        int16_t tempDepartment;
        std::stringstream(lineList[8]) >> tempDepartment;
        emp->department = tempDepartment;
        employeeArrayN.resize(empNumN);
        employeeArrayN[empNumN - 1] = *emp;
        std::cout << "Added new employe: [ID " << emp->id << "] " << emp->lastName << ", " << emp->firstName << " " << emp->middleInitial << ". \n";
    }
    file.close();
    return true;
}
//...snip...//

//fix is a function I added just for this question, I wouldn't want to bother you with my monolithic actual function//
void fix()
{
    bool notGonnaUse = loadFromDatabaseFileN();
}
```

Comment: Your code has several possible sources of undefined behaviour. For example, perhaps `lineList[8]` is out of bounds of the vector, or perhaps any of the `>>` fail, leaving an indeterminate value which you then read.    Try [debugging your code](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you want someone else to debug it for you then you need to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the exact input file you provided which gave the problem, so that someone else can reproduce your results.

Comment: You leak memory (there is no `delete` corresponding to `new Employee`), but that is probably unrelated to the segfault

Comment: You aren't showing the input file... Also, to see where segmentation fault happens, please use debugger to examine the call stack. `std::ifstream file(filename)` is very very unlikely to crash, unless you first have memory corruption. For example, check that `lineList` really has 9 elements, before proceeding to access index 8...

Comment: Also, look up `std::vector::push_back` method, and use it instead of your current method of using `resize`.

Comment: @M.M This is getting very weird. I already ran debugging on my program, and the debugger gave me a SIGSEGV on ifstream. Now, however, after adding code, the debugger gives me a SIGSEGV on emp->firstName = lineList[2]. Now, normally, I would debug this part, but the problem here is that that line is after 4 cout breakpoints, all of which should have printed, but didn't.

Comment: If you didn't also output a newline and `flush`, you may not see the output when breakpoint is hit.  You could try replacing `lineList[n]` with `linelist.at(n)`, then you will get an exception instead of undefined behaviour. Alternatively, check `lineLine.size() >= 8` before embarking on that series.  The error on commented-out line could be explained by not actually rebuilding the code before running the changed version.  The most productive approach is probably still to create a MCVE.

Answer (score -1):

This may not fix your problem but...

Using

```
while ( file )
{
   ...
   std::getline(file, lineInput);
   ...
}
```

is a problem. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Using

```
while ( file ) { }
```

suffers from the same problems as using:

```
while ( !file.eof() ) { }
```

Change that code to use:

```
// Move the declaration of lineInput out of the loop.
std::string lineInput;
while ( std::getline(file, lineInput) )
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: note: even if this fixes the problem, it would be good to continue to debug the original crash -- a program should not be able to crash just by being given some particular input file, this leads to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @PracticalProblems, I can't see any other problem in your code. You may want to try the divide and conquer approach.